# how to reach the end of file

Tags: c++, file, struct

I have a function that gets some information from a file and puts it in a structure. i set a loop(with **for** and **while** both) with the condition that it goes on until it reaches at the end of file. 
but it doesn't work.

```
void FileToStructProfessors()
{
     int n;
     fstream CurrentFile("professor.txt");
     if (!CurrentFile)
     {
         cout <<"can't open file";
     }
     else
     {
         CurrentFile.seekp(5);
         /*for(n=0;CurrentFile.eof();n++)
         {
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].FirstName;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].LastName;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].PID;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].Major;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].Level;
             CurrentFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
             cout<<P1[0].FirstName<<endl;

         }*/
         n=0;
         while(!CurrentFile.eof())
         {
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].FirstName;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].LastName;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].PID;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].Major;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].Level;
             CurrentFile>>P1[n].Date;
             CurrentFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
             cout<<P1[3].FirstName<<endl; 
             n++;               
         }
     }
     CurrentFile.close();
}
```

professor.txt

```
4

hamed
hamidi
1001
civil
associate professor
91/02/15

morteza
jafari
1005
computer
assistant professor
91/01/20

mahdi
foladi
1006
computer
professor
90/10/10

mostafa
mohammadi
1009
electronic
assistant professor
91/05/5
```

**for the professor structure**

```
struct Professors
{
       string FirstName,LastName;
       long long int PID;
       string Major,Level,Date;
}P1[100];
```

Comment: @user2589043 Don't use `if(!currentFile)`, use `if(!currentFile.fail())`.

Comment: @user2589043 Give my answer a try, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're reading trying to read lines, but `CurrentFile >>` ignores **all** whitespace, including spaces. So when you read the first professor:

```
med
hamidi
1001
civil
associate professor
91/02/15
```

You'll get:

```
FirstName = med
LastName = hamidi
PID = 1001
Major = civil
Level = associate
Date = professor
```

There's a space between 'associate' and 'professor', so `CurrentFile >> P1[n].Level` only picks up 'associate' because `CurrentFile >>` sees the space and stops. Then your next `CurrentFile >>` picks up 'professor' instead of the date you want to read. Compound this over the whole file, and you'll get a lot of input that doesn't make sense.

You can fix this with `getline(CurrentFile, *string you want to read in*)`, as in the following sample. *Note that this is not production-quality code, just a simple toy example illustrating `getline` intended to get you moving forward with your project.*

```
void FileToStructProfessors()
{
    int n;
    fstream CurrentFile("professor.txt");
    if (CurrentFile.fail())
    {
        cout <<"can't open file";
        // Put a return here so you don't
        // try to `.close()` the file later.
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(CurrentFile.good())
        {
            getline(CurrentFile, P1[n].FirstName);
            getline(CurrentFile, P1[n].LastName);

            // PID is an integer, and getline doesn't work with integers,
            // only strings. You can try simply 'CurrentFile >> P1[n].PID;',
            // but this will mess up the next getline (try it yourself if you
            // want). We can get around this using a stringstream, so put
            // '#include <sstream>' at the top of your file.
            string s;  
            getline(CurrentFile, s);
            istringstream iss(s);
            iss >> P1[n].PID;

            getline(CurrentFile, P1[n].Major);
            getline(CurrentFile, P1[n].Level);
            getline(CurrentFile, P1[n].Date);

            // This is to read past the blank line that
            // separates your entries.
            getline(CurrentFile, s);

            // Print stuff.

            n++;               
        }
    }

    CurrentFile.close();
}
```

**By the way, I removed:**

1. `CurrentFile.seekp(5)`.
2. `CurrentFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

**Note**

My example is not safe/correct, because any of those `getline` calls or `CurrentFile >>` statements could encounter an error, and *none of them are checked for error*. I wrote this to be a relatively simple-to-understand explanation of why your code is having an issue. For code that is safe/correct please take a look at [0x499602D2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21066347/3171324).

Comment: Both of those exhibit the same problem.  The file won't be bad until a read fails, likely due to eof.

Comment: Well I was assuming that 1) the file was opened correctly, and 2) he/she knows the number and order of the entries in the file, so there  are exactly as many reads as can fit before EOF is hit. I'd like to see the file to really be sure.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the 'professor.txt' file you open?

Comment: i added the text file.

Comment: Make sure you're not continuing the above with: `while(currentFile.good()) { currentFile.read(..); use_input_from_file(); }` because that could really result in failure

Comment: This answer is wrong. Both code examples are not good code and **will** lead to problems.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's not *wrong* in that it works for his particular situation. Is it production-quality code? Certainly not, you're right about that. Is it code that a beginner can start to play with? Yes, which is why I put it up here.

Comment: @Keeler But wouldn't you agree that at least telling him about the correct way to use IOStreams is a good thing to do? He'll leave thinking that `while (good())` or `while (eof())` is correct when it is not.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I do agree. But I think my answer is better in this situation (personally :)) because it addresses the root issue (whitespace) in a beginner-friendly manner. I linked to your answer, because you are technically correct.

Comment: i used your code ,it compiles but suddenly stops working and doesn't work.

Comment: Well, my sample worked in my code. Since you didn't post a full code sample, I had to guess how you initialized `P1` and how you defined the `Professor` struct. Can you be more specific with the error?

Comment: all my code is about 300 lines, it's a lot!but i can post the professor struct, and the error is it doesn't work. it stops working. and another problem is when i run the code in another project it works but in my program it does't

Comment: @user2589043 Well, I'd imagine there are other errors in your code. Welcome to the wonderful world of programming! However, the issue you mentioned in the question is solved by the answers here. Figure out more precisely what your current issue is, then open a new question if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition for performing input shouldn't be predicated upon the acquisition of the end of the file. Performing input only until the input *fails* is the conventional condition for performing extraction. Doing otherwise causes unwanted behavior.

Therefore you should check if the stream doesn't have `std::ios_base::failbit` or `std::ios_base::badbit` set. Checking both of these bits is necessary because `failbit` represents an error in parsing where the stream could not successfully extract, and `badbit` represents a problem with the external device (a likely irrecoverable error). Both contribute to failure to extract. But this all needs to be done *after* the input is attempted.

Here is the above task represented using your code:

> ```
> while (  CurrentFile >> P1[n].FirstName &&
>          CurrentFile >> P1[n].LastName  &&
>          CurrentFile >> P1[n].PID       &&
>          CurrentFile >> P1[n].Major     &&
>          std::getline(CurrentFile >> std::ws, P1[n].Level) &&
>          std::getline(CurrentFile >> std::ws, P1[n].Date) )
> ```

Notice how I've also changed the last two extractions by using `std::getline()`. This is because corresponding data in the file contains spaces which formatted operators use as a delimiter. The date uses slashes which are also delimited upon when using formatted input. Following that, the `Level` and `Date` data members will have to be `std::string`s and you will need to use *unformatted* input.

If any one of the extractions fail, the stream will set the appropriate bits. The stream will then be implicitly converted to a boolean using `operator bool()` (or `operator void*()` pre-C++11 where it will subsequently undergo promotion to boolean). The boolean operation will check the stream state using `!this->fail()` (which checks both `badbit` and `failbit`) and if the function returns true, the entire `while` loop expression is false and the remaining extractions will not be performed (because of short-circuit evaluation).

If the stream is still in a good state (`!this->fail()` returns `true`), the loop body will be executed. If the stream encounters the EOF character while performing extraction, the `eofbit` will be set, but the loop will not stop until a later attempted input operation fails to  successfully extract. This is the desired behavior.

Comment: This may be safer than my example, but it will not work for this file. See my answer for the reason why (spaces in the professor 'level' that gets read).

Comment: You mention that `getline` delimits on slashes, but I don't think this is accurate. A call to `getline(someStream, someString);` will delimit on `\n` by default, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Keeler I was referring to formatted input: `cin >> someInt;`. The stream will stop extracting when it encounters a character that doesn't fit the formatting requirements for the type. Such a character can be a non-integral character like `'/'`. So in a way, the stream does "delimit" by those class of characters. But I understand how it can be seen as an inaccurate word in this case.

Comment: That's completely accurate. It was unclear in the context of your answer that you were referring to `cin >> someInt`, thanks for clarifying what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

#### Improving your program:

That was the crux of your problem. You didn't understand how stream input was intended to be performed. I don't know who taught you `while (!file.eof())`, but it is almost always the wrong way to go.

Your program is good, but it isn't perfect. If you want to know how to improve your program, keep reading, otherwise I hope that my other answer helped.

You didn't show us the relevant code, but I'm assuming `P1` is a static array with a default size (that size being 4). Your code is potentially dangerous as the index `n` increases along with the contents of the file. If you had more than 4 "groups" of data that were to be extracted into the array, your program would invoke Undefined Behavior.

To circumvent this potential problem, you can use a dynamic container like `std::vector<T>`. It will allocate an internal array of an appropriate size and dynamically-resize if needed. You can specify the size at construction like the following:

> ```
> CurrentFile >> size;
> std::vector<Professor> P1(size);
> ```

Adding data to this container is as simple as `P1.push_back(p)`. You no longer need a counter.

---

`CurrentFile.seekp(5)` makes no sense because the stream is being used for input and that will only affect the output pointers. If you wanted to ignore the first integer, you can simply extract into a dummy variable. But since I have already done that above, that is not necessary. If you're trying to ignore the whitespace between the integer at the top of the file at the name of the first `Professor`, that is again unneeded because formatted extractors automatically discard leading whitespace from the input sequence. You need not worry about whitespace being inadvertently extracted.

This also renders the following code unnecessary:

```
CurrentFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

The above code was present in your while loop (I believe) in an attempt to discard the whitespace and newlines so that the next character available to extract is the name of the next professor. This isn't needed for the same reason above.

---

And lastly, in order to facilitate extraction into an object of type `Project`, it is recommended you implement your own extractor using operator overloading. It keeps the rest of your code clean and coherent.